# How do I choose where to position a mini-map in the HUD?

Tags: maps, hud

In a game with a minimap, what factors should be considered when choosing where to put the minimap on the screen HUD? What choices are typically made when wanting to emphasize a particular factor?

Comment: I don't think this is a question which fits in here. Mostly the minimap is in one of the four corners, which one you should decide yourself.

Comment: I am asking what is the most common position. It is part of game development

Comment: "Most common" doesn't mean "best", since the best choice depends on the game. After Lærne's edit, this question looks promising and useful though. It's in the reopen-vote-queue.

Comment: Yes. That was my point to be honest but I phrased it completely wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no clearly "most common" position beside one the four corners.  If you an information band/ribbon/... you typically want to embed it in your information ribbon, and leave the viewport as clean as possible.  Since it's usually one of the biggest and more visual element to display in a HUD, you often want to push it to the corner to avoid it to be too distracting/overlapping.  The band, when there is one, has often been place on the bottom, so it's no surprise, the minimap is often on the bottom left or bottom right in many games, especially RTS.  Here is *Dota 2* and *league of legends*:

[image: Moba with bottom left minimap]
[image: Moba with bottom right minimap]

But other games have the band above, so the minimap is above.  *On binding of isaac*, it's on the top left
[image]

Other have the band on the left or right, so the minimap is on the left or right.  I can't remember a recent game with a left band, so here is *populous : the beginning*, with the minimap top left.
[image]

If you do not have a band in your HUD, put it where it hides the least interesting part of the viewport.

However if your minimap is very, very important and you cannot go around without, you can center it on the top or bottom edge of the screen, like *star citizen* or *elite dangerous* (which besides embed their minimap in the game world).

[image]
Without knowing what kind of game you want to make, that's all help we can give.

Comment: Actually, many games that require a certain amount of navigation show you the minimap overlayed at the center of the screen, so you can focus on navigating when you need so.

Comment: Yeah, I though of it but actually it's usually a feature to enable/disable when you're lost, I guessed it's more akin to check a full regular map by pressing a key or to play just with the map than to have a minimap.  I should also have mentioned the 3DS ability to display the game world on one screen, and the map on the other.  Feel free to improve my answer.